# GestureDetector in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, pinchzoom, gesturedetector

I am new in libgdx. I have the following problem. I want to do pinch zooming for my game. For that I have `GestureDetectorListener` class in my `GameStage`.

In `GameStage` I have the following code for `GestureDetector`:

```
OrthographicCamera camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
this.setCamera(camera);


GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(20, 0.5f, 2, 0.15f, new GestureDetectorListener());
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gestureDetector);

class GestureDetectorListener implements GestureListener {
    float initialScale = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        initialScale = camera.zoom;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
        float ratio = initialDistance / distance;
        camera.zoom = initialScale * ratio;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2,
            Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Also I have set `InputListener` for the Actors of my stage, in order to drag them. The problem is that, when I set `InputProcessor` to `GestureDetector`, dragging of my Actors is not working. I want to have a pinch zooming with camera and `GestureDetector`, but it will not have an influence on dragging. How can I do that?

Any help please!
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CodeNoob is on the right path, but I think you may want to structure things differently.

You can use an [`InputMultiplexer`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html) to install both a global `GestureListener` and your stage's listener:

```
GestureDetector gd = ...
Stage myStage = ...
InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer(gd, myStage); // Order matters here!
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
```

The other thing to watch out for is the return values on all the `boolean` methods in your input listeners.  Any one that returns "true" will mark the event as "handled" and the multiplexer will not pass the event on to its peer.  Also, the order of the input processors in the multiplexer makes a difference (as it may hide events from the underlying inputProcessor).  So, the auto-generated stubs returning 'true' in your example, will "eat" a bunch of events.  If this handler is first in the multiplexer, that will hide events from the stage.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. "return true" was the problem. And now dragging and zooming are working. But I want that zooming affects not the whole stage, but on some container. I guess I can't use camera, because camera is set for the whole stage.

Comment: What you think about it? Can I set the camera for some container, not the whole stage? Thanks.

Comment: Correct, changing the camera changes how your model space is mapped to the entire screen, so its not quite the right thing for zooming just one container.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a InputMultiplexer `InputMultiplexer myInputMultiplexer = new InputMultiplexer()`

Then you add your both GestureDetector and InputListener to the InputMultiplexer (`myInputMultiplexer.addProcessor()`).

And at the End, you have to set the multiplexer as the main InputProcessor like this: `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(myInputMultiplexer)`

Comment: I believe the `InputMultiplexer` is only needed to multiplex listeners outside a `Stage`.  The questioner has one listener inside the stage, and one listener outside.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved the problem with InputMultiplexer.